# tmux send-keys syntax

Tags: tmux

On the tmux man page I found no reference to how it names keys.

For example, to send <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> to tmux you would do:

```
tmux send-keys C-r
```

and to send the <kbd>esc</kbd> key you do

```
tmux send-keys Escape
```

Is there a list which maps keyboard keys to how tmux sendkeys expects you to name them? I have a feeling that I missed a memo that its using *some-long-forgotten-program's* syntax for convenience.

Note, this is nothing to do with key bindings.

Comment: I'm used to "^r" being control+r. Whence cometh this outlandish alternate syntax?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The key names used by `send-keys` are the same ones that `bind-key` uses.
From the [*Key Bindings* section](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#KEY_BINDINGS) of the [*tmux* manpage](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1):

> When specifying keys, most represent themselves (for example ‘A’ to
>        ‘Z’).  Ctrl keys may be prefixed with ‘C-’ or ‘^’, and Alt (meta) with
>        ‘M-’.  In addition, the following special key names are accepted: *Up*,
>        *Down*, *Left*, *Right*, *BSpace*, *BTab*, *DC* (Delete), *End*, *Enter*, *Escape*, *F1* to
>        *F20*, *Home*, *IC* (Insert), *NPage/PageDown/PgDn*, *PPage/PageUp/PgUp*, *Space*,
>        and *Tab*.

Although they are not listed in the man page, there are also special names for keypad-specific keys: `KP0` through `KP9`, `KP/`, `KP*`, `KP-`, `KP+`, `KP.`, and `KPEnter`.

Several of the more cryptic key names (`BTab`, `IC`, `DC`, `NPage`, `PPage`) probably come from the *terminfo* library.

*Emacs* shares the convention of using `C-` and `M-` prefixes to indicate modifiers (I would not be surprised if there were earlier uses of this convention).

Comment: is there a way to escape these binded keys? Say I want to send the literal string `enter` - what send-keys do is to send the named key "Enter"

Comment: @ItamarKatz: Use the `-l` (“literal”) flag: `send-keys -l Enter` will send the five letters: `E` `n` `t` `e` `r` (*tmux* 1.7+; for prior versions, break them up a bit: e.g. `send-keys E nter`).

Comment: If you want to send a command and press enter, using space to separate them: `send-keys "ls" Enter`

Comment: How about sending `CTRL + C` to terminate whatever runing in tmux?

Comment: @weefwefwqg3 `tmux send-keys -t $PANE_ID C-c`